# Dúvidas para desenvolvimento de app com swift

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, swift, apple

Estou trabalhando com um app para iOS e estou usando Swift. O meu cliente que é dono de um restaurante gostaria de usar um painel administrativo para adicionar novos pratos ao app.

Gostaria de saber se há um painel na net que já faça algo assim ou se terei de criá-lo. Se for criá-lo, qual linguagem usar que dê para depois integrar com o app iOS?

Answer (score 2):

> Se for criá-lo, qual linguagem usar que dê para depois integrar com o
>   app iOS?

Você precisa ter um fluxo de informações definido para o seu aplicativo mobile e para sua aplicação WEB.

Normalmente, é necessário um `webservice` responsável por encapsular sua regra de negócio e realizar as operações necessárias para o seu sistema. O aplicativo `iOS` e a aplicação web devem consumir os serviços deste `webservice`.

A linguagem de programação utilizada no aplicativo iOS, na página WEB e no webservice são independentes e não se relacionam. Você pode, por exemplo, criar um aplicativo iOS em SWIFT, um `webservice` em `C#` e uma aplicação web com `angular js`.

> Gostaria de saber se há um painel na net que já faça algo assim ou se
>   terei de criá-lo.

Você pode utilizar [templates do bootstrap](http://www.bootstrapzero.com/) para a parte visual, existem muitos que simulam um painel administrativo, mas desconheço um aplicativo já implementado com as configurações necessárias para integrar com seu `webservice`. Neste caso, seria necessário realizar as operações de chamada ao `webservice` e tratar seu retorno na aplicação web.